# How to uninstall or revert back to older version of Google play services and Google Repository files in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, android-sdk-tools

Recently i have updated Google play services from Revision 29 to 30 and Google Repository files from Revision 25 to 27.

These new versions are giving lots of errors in the project code, how to revert back to older versions of google play services and google repository files.

How to delete the latest installed updates, so that i can use the older versions. Im using eclipse.

Comment: You don't need to delete the installed files, simply change your gradle file to specify the appropriate version you wish to use

Comment: @chRyNaN im using eclipse, ill soon update but for now i need to revert back to older versions, is there any way?